# How to color numbers in axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tkz-collection

I want to color the numbers 3 in blue and -1 in green as show in the picture below.
[image]

My code is this :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzInit[xmin=-4.5,xmax=4,xstep=1]
 \tkzAxeX[label={}]
 \coordinate (A) at (3,0);
 \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
 \coordinate (B) at (-1,0);
 \coordinate (C) at (.5,.7);
 \coordinate (D) at (4,.7);
 \coordinate (E) at (-.5,.7);
 \coordinate (F) at (-4,.7);
 \tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick, color=blue](O,A)
 \tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick, color=green](O,B)
 \tkzDrawSegments[dashed](O,C C,D O,E E,F)
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use the tkz-euclide package

Comment: Can you make the code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I don't know how to change the color of only a few numbers defined with `\tkzInit`, but a temporary (i.e. not really proper) solution would be adding nodes like `\node[color=blue] at (3,-.34) {3};`.

Comment: It's not possible with `\tkzAxeX`because this macro is used to get general result. The best solution is to place the numbers with tikz manually.

Comment: Another possibility is to write a new macro ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First remark. The tkz collection is created to do some automatic pictures with general options. If you want to create specific pictures with a flexible method, I think it's better to learn Tikz and to use it.

Manually, you need to use `\tkzDrawX[label={}]` instead of `\tkzAxeX`. The  solution is possible because in your code you have `xstep=1` and you use a lot default options.
Another method is to overwrite some nodes with color and `fill=white` (if the background is white)

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-4.5,xmax=4]
  \tkzDrawX[label={}]
  \coordinate (A) at (3,0);
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (-1,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (.5,.7);
  \coordinate (D) at (4,.7);
  \coordinate (E) at (-.5,.7);
  \coordinate (F) at (-4,.7);
  \tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick, color=blue](O,A)
  \tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick, color=green](O,B)
  \tkzDrawSegments[dashed](O,C C,D O,E E,F)
  \node[below,text=green] at (-1,0) {$-1$};
   \node[below,text=blue] at (3,0) {$3$};
   \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,0,1,2,4}  \node[below,] at (\x,0) {$\x$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Second method with default options. It's not very fine but you get the result that you want

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-4.5,xmax=4,xstep=1]
  \tkzAxeX[label={}]
  \coordinate (A) at (3,0);
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (-1,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (.5,.7);
  \coordinate (D) at (4,.7);
  \coordinate (E) at (-.5,.7);
  \coordinate (F) at (-4,.7);
  \tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick, color=blue](O,A)
  \tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick, color=green](O,B)
  \tkzDrawSegments[dashed](O,C C,D O,E E,F)
  \node[below=2pt,text=blue,fill=white] at (3,0) {$3$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I think the first solution is better thanks!